# Double sided printing on Epson ET-4550

Tags: printer, epson-ecotank

Since installing Windows 10, my Epson printer has refused to print on both sides of a sheet of paper, which it has happily been doing since I purchased it many years ago.

When clicking preferences, it tells me

```
---------------------------
EPSON ET-4550 Series
---------------------------
Some settings cannot be changed because Administrator Lock has been enabled.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd4/cpd41361/source/printers/source/printing_software/windows_fy13/tasks/locking_printer_settings_windows_fy14.html explains how to disable the Administrator Lock. Since a search of Epson's website does not show an update for Windows 10, follow the Windows 8 instructions:

Navigate to the Apps screen and select Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers.

Right-click your product and select Printer properties.

Click the Optional Settings tab.

Click Driver Settings. You see this window:

[image: Driver Settings window picture]

Select the checkbox for the function or functions you want to lock. To lock all print settings, select All Document Settings.

Under Advanced Settings, select the setting you want for each selected function (in this case, double-sided printing).

Click OK.